# Mongo how to exclude nested _id in the nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to exclude nested default `_id` in every element of array in the founded result.
I have next request. In some fields `_id` property can be absent.
How can I exclude it in the filters ?
Is it possible?

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({"name":"t1"},{"_id":0})
```

I get next data from DB

```
       {
            "array" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id": ObjectId("5685ea32ba5298688d27cceb"),
                            "id" : 1,
                            "name" : "aaa"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_id": ObjectId("5685ea32ba5298688d27cceb"),
                            "id" : 2,
                            "name" : "bbb"
                        },
                        {
                            "id" : 3,
                            "name" : "bbb"
                        },
            ]
}
```

I want to get next array without `_id`

```
       {
            "array" : [ 
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "name" : "aaa"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "id" : 2,
                            "name" : "bbb"
                        },
            ]
}
```

When I try to use

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({"name":"t1"},{"_id":0, "array._id":0})
```

I get the error like:

> "errmsg" : "Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.",
> I think the reason that some objects of array don't contain the `_id` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` is inside an array field, so you have to use `array._id`,

```
db.getCollection('Test').find(
  { "name": "t1" },
  { "array._id": 0 }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/krjq0xhZ6JV),
[Mongo Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLEc4.png)

Comment: Unfortunately I have got the error like: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion. Also I have expect that _id will be excluded for all elements in array

Comment: so have you tried same query that in answer? yes this answer is for to exclude the _id from array

Comment: yes, I have tried on the real request and it didn't help but I will include instead exclude. Mb it is not right way but db.getCollection('Test').find({"name":"t1"},{"_id":0, "array.name": 1,"array.id":1 }) it works

Comment: i am not getting you exactly how are you using this but look at this query https://mongoplayground.net/p/krjq0xhZ6JV , this returns your expected result, if you want something other then please update your question.

Comment: Yes you are right. As I understood in some records of the nested arrays _id can be present in other no

Comment: When I try on the https://mongoplayground.net/p/6QshsJR9PSI it works well. But on the real server not.

Comment: In which server you are exhibiting this query?

Comment: look at the screenshot of mongo shell attached in answer

Comment: If you can, please insert one element without _id property and other with _id. And try to make request

Comment: its working perfectly, i think you are doing something wrong.